# Скачать файл по URL, используя HTTPClient

Tags: android, http

Пытаюсь реализовать загрузку файла по его URL. Вот, что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

client.get(editText.getText().toString(), new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(getApplicationContext()) {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, File file) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка загрузки", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File file) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Загрузка завершена", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        File f = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), file.getName());
        try {
            if (f.createNewFile())
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Загрузка завершена", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка загрузки", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка загрузки", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     }
});
```

В результате создается файл нулевого размера без расширения. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Что за класс `AsyncHttpClient`?

Comment: @eugeneek http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ Добавлен ли permission на запись в AndroidManifest? В урле точно содержится протокол?

Comment: Здрквствуйте, вот есть похожий вопрос, ответ 100% работает, проверял на собственном проекте, возможно он Вам подойдет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog Можно отвязать ProgressBar и да, не забудьте про манифест

Comment: @АндроидАндроид вот примеры url: https://pp.userapi.com/c841628/v841628182/744b3/B5llJWlJ06M.jpg https://pp.userapi.com/c824600/v824600168/d3bbc/w8Bnm9vSbt4.jpg . В манифесте прописано     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />, также запрашиваю разрешение программно